# Public dataset for news articles with their associated categories for multilabel data classification

Tags: dataset, bigdata, multilabel-classification, text-classification

I am wondering if there are any public datasets of news, like The New York Times (NYT) or similar to various news categories such as politics, entertainment, lifestyle, general news, sports, etc.

I want to use such a dataset for multilabel data classification of various sentences or paragraphs, i.e., a sentence could belong to politics, entertainment, sports, or all, so I need the dataset to classify the data into more than one label. I was planning to train a classifier with such a dataset and use it for predictions. However, I couldn't find any. Are there any such known datasets available?

I want a dataset that is something like this, but for news categories:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found one on [Kaggle](http://kaggle.com/) by searching "news categories". I believe [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rmisra/news-category-dataset) should work for you. Its a JSON file which contains a link to the article, an associated category (e.g. "crime"), headline, authors, date, and a short description.

You may also want to check out the Open Data Stackexchange:

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Enjoy!

https://www.kaggle.com/rmisra/news-category-dataset

Comment: I have already gone through this dataset but I wonder if this will help as I want the dataset that contains an article and associated categories i.e suppose an article A should have categories both crime and business i.e a news can be crime and business news both.